# display resolution question

Tags: 12.04, video, configuration, display

My machine has two hard drives, one has Fedora 64bit and one has Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. When running Fedora, I can set the resolution to 1600x1200. But I can only get 1280x1024 when Ubuntu is running.

How can I get the same resolution as when Fedora is running? One dell monitor in my case.

**EDIT:**

More info here:

**lspci | grep -i vga** shows:

```
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV37GL [Quadro PCI-E Series] (rev a2)
```

**sudo lshw -C video** shows:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
product: NV37GL [Quadro PCI-E Series]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
version: a2
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:de000000-deffffff memory:df800000-df81ffff
```

**xrandr** shows:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1280x1024 0.0*
1024x768 0.0
800x600 0.0
640x480 0.0
```

**lsmod |grep nvidia** shows:
nothing

So it seems there is no driver installed? how to install the driver?

Comment: And you are using the same graphic drivers in both I guess?

Comment: no hardware changes when I switch from one to another.

Comment: What drivers have you enabled in Fedora and Ubuntu, namely the ones for the graphics card? What model graphics card is it?

Comment: more info is added which include the graphic card info.